# Sequential LED turn signal + pulse sequence

Tags: led, digital-logic, circuit-design, comparator, 555

I'm trying to build an LED circuit what outputs 2 different sequential patterns. The first patterns is a 7 LED sequential turn signal using the ne555 timer module. I'm trying to make the LEDs progressively turn on and then progressively turn of one after another. one it goes through the sequence then the second LED pattern must be activated which does a pulse wave pattern starting from the middle of the 7 LEDs. Below I've included what I've done so far. Ultimately, I need to combine these to sequence LED patterns using ICs and push button. Any advice would be appreciated. I'm using Falstad and need to also build the circuit  on a breadboard.

This is what the output should look like with everything combined:
**[Video link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/172rcJYwMX-m9tA69nVCxzLMwe4swNYRD?usp=share_link)**

pattern 1 (turn signal sequence): (circuit #2 bottom [link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0mRAWATLArATgMwIfJlMAOTTEHEVM01AUwFowwAoAJRAckMPaQHYl2jfD35Rw4aJUqQxMVEwDm7dOTqYBdFQnAA2WUwDugztzp8NYSKj1nRkQ8esiN6dBvNQHmt8-aF0Nh72AMZ%20AYK8Nv42OtoyMHCJrskpqa4SGDiu2Bg6OmCYvFCw8IphMdp00bKebFVw7Jg6poSxjc01uCDoNXJMAE5%20DWoddDpOI9wylokD7OM2TaYLPFximOj2AIbsGBqYqBoI4WqHINxglAyUM4nT0LyRXDoEqJgFcEikYJJa2Qi5fKFcB3exGMYTJa7HyTTzgvaNJrzNZqJHbaHuUR0Y6BUQXK6XEGgiTHVBgQgAzY6Tb4Ho-TLHLCUvIFIq3OBMHZ0BEMGE4wQ%20fGCG6g%205IAoIYhgBAvHS8BBgPT0v5MwGsomzLkIyXsfk6oXXDWJYpLQpcMDi1wENm-LKqgJAtmgzkYxpHE7qc7gAki4kwcZwQiQJDWQji4gZFU5B3q9no7kwoS6k5Jg2EuPxaBYMC8Qg5%20A4GVfSN26Ms4Fxrw8pAolZmNZg11mCbNUwhvSNhPuTjzCb4KZVxORZGmHMdwcWGu9mwWgfwmEnVvKcfzo7LCY6zs8xUjwQr12eiF6T1bnxtMZrNr2QZH1brwI9mQba-Tng928MKdPzZzD%20z1-YlMIDPr%20dY6reJ7AT%204JLqiMQou2cK7s28GjsOnawWOyHhBhKKLiiO64aOqEgFeXjVAww4Xmh%205VCcHh0TYCq0RRzHnDI2KEQ4Qa6juPGnAIL78QcAjCZAcQgPgTCKqJHGYOJ7E8E4AgACY0AAZlsACuAA2AAudA6TQKniPExSlIMh4icB%20wKTIUk3juAl7o0dmSfYMk2a52iHohqkadp%20mGcZpmyLAzCeQwiwKVFSl6P5mm6QZRkmRAZkJBFOgWC83l7hxfkgGpiVBSloWZqUkVJmoMVVQVRWBclIVpWFFl5Y0ZxRXJbkOYIFrtRYfXVRJUmRee8mVOedUBUlwWpb04WgZU1ljEt3UvmY77Lf2uX2R5WVvqY40HXFkmFdNJVNfNpRGMJZxWWcjb3dl-VIbFzkrS9GFLR1VXWZ2v0-Tlzn-UDW2bQ9v78u9bHAxqkP0ViMNBHDN5Q2AfJOejgko8mM6DTDSbTLMqMekcTmQbc8N6OBbGbnD4Iw1tkIQ%20CiHvWz22dkjWI1m2dheATMLqBxWOvbzvj1jRr3CwK%20zCAw5D2HpsuCKoVXShJaXQCyViEKgrStOS6CEEUMD8GGLzoLwhzynruZEmdxV6UwysocdG1to%204i8lm1JuEgSB5PKqBWMKJRwOS%20DYJK8C%20o7DUuzwSCVFhnURB2pna-kutvAW-CQPkxTm4HkAOjHWD%20A79VJYnn6joN56E5nOv67EByRJSPRmzWJfG7gzSPOmDTV-ptf8fxTk8dMxQtybnybJshEPD3ltuK0gdht8w-nc7ruHjq%209AVrs-W7wcCHJHRcrzMirWPr6AQDM8c16zBFUQHKfoV4MsKyniaKwLTGg1-wMD6p2babsPZJziF4RU%20UJhwJVv9QabN1Y5S%20idD6ddXpOVQTYHCDhfJOEPGRBm5NspyUErA0GFChg4KBuPDiU9AHU1MOETcXh2FsKYnOZcupDprk8EoKBvJuwXC-EItqac07-niGUUBk564CFkZIrBi5tAqPsMIpyjclQSK0V5NQAhPSaLKPxRCPFTE3hWIeXMPlsZkgMXQOxhiXFT08DeCiDEKJYXsiHDk4IfFUS0OnV6ITKL4LVl%20WBVhcQWFiXQ%20wABJRwUQOIBCYelSQFBpIYGUFEthqhILCAzHcGJyd2AuI4F0ZxFJXpPFSe7SwThOwNI4BMNp1ROytBTgk5xoxmnjhvOEwZfhG4JKJgE5QiY%20kjImZwmEPTpnxJaQsjQSz2lRFIcuJh55XDrLIsIjZQZdmVGttjEIjSqiHlGc4tE5k7haySGkZI6MQ5WwecwcEtziAuAYSeGJEwNk-IBY5PplgKmbLGcNMpdRbkQpThaEWwYJIyC6F3MK8hAkphRVchFr0TnKCnNclw0TAnDHxfUdJZLyjGEhYSjgFTuknH2bSxlMDAmHgogyrp1C8XEtGetEBtyIGCqNFWYBSLdiDVZY2RuUruSSuEHK3poh5XKsIQM8SMhxldHsOpFyULxnEOUdkhISBpLjB2daqo-EMmkXOFmB%20kdLh5BwGSXJPQPznIAisXaRpRRMBSf00wZ8JpYjDZinJ4JOknDaZGjCQLhh1h9Rhd8DK6yEvWi8Foi500NEmU4qGPJi2Kw8e0UwJaTgIhkI4soUJbVPlGPyORSgf42Pli2yRDElwMS7QYj%20lThCDuxDhSRqcfWp37WUEBLiQHTqUOPPiHFp1GFFmMUQbM5RULXTCVAw513bpwcS-dSo91fzXcSyNECE0OBASsWddlYHEofS%201ZRgf5cCfPLJcjZvE8QYvnJCI6v2SUhamu9VFQMTrqY2EB0HiV5n3OPHi48OHfKvUiRBdzaK2I6HGjojZMk6sqFmxOW7RDtrsN7cUDw3hrzPvrY4koLCoHDvAdAId-B63NFXHe5H3zXojW5CAZgfjWw2PuikGArYjsuOxhAkReAP3ku8LeMgR6710BxXgSIR26YzqJ2jEm%205MZlLpyARRrjsethSNw8oHN8adonc8hL4MFpo%20J1AuANj2Z0EQfzYdEgFHDJx-z%20QnQaf48rLlnpx4Ux4F53AunT0KkDt5oLEcXgHCtpwcSGjt7OeVgRi4VEGnTzE3R3A4kySnzgF6%20TwXtXowVA-HwT9NPf3WeQyphGHBMLHVS49LQetVC4hh3NGdGJIUPFbY86yAUTeUMOWbX8bwQNPYIE96EcYiLrPelpu2b1ImwThsQlN1vpsxohwiR300pkQ2Oi77s5tbbYTtyml73t6DtRe8AwSD3Ete3%20yFr3U7A4cAxV7I6IcfvltDrEsPgKjFez-CHnk7VThQ-ZZ%20F05pZNar9n71Kj7EzA5UaHoOJGU08jDqcIGAO48avjlqzBBjg4PcE6nZOQFg6B9zjknlwdTlTqBhKDVZplXMplZR-PxEtEZ5pyXzVyoy8koj%20nWIxdM%20V1dNXaOpyfsVzvXXBO2fq5cMOKHAuXxo5W-Dm3lrjEo8N6MbXSvSoq%20l3MBtqOXek6mQ2ywXRfd-bGPmldwwyMM2TTU6rux0EC2GEB7Ese5Ex%20I7qZPGqM9%20H4vHobXNhj2tT0w5hN4G1HthF2dYP4K%20jB9dXo9351oNt%20RWypD0oKt5R4NNvkEQLgiOtyIGBfrDp9yjX6vNbv4xViJHji8-pZz6xJX-mQ%20Yop4L0Bzsw-G8Nogxv0jwwC-R8n%2036v7fd8xVA6XvPE%20hrKD773qhXI98neOz970woA2ZmzLmfMDWIsDYYoHMJAB%20fwAgPWYMQOR%20Z0N-OfPsd8FYNMX0O4GefxIMdsMMckeSU2aAMAiAzYIgEOAOQuSsBAyoTbERTbVA3-E0ZoM0PMS0Yg%20UUA-gIgqA0g2AgNF0R-MbB8EbL-QkQ0DMCQcUbAKUGUAueUHMLWQgo2LgmA8g%20A8-eie7YQn0egn4UkckSkAuGkSweQjgxQkg5QuAspI-G1Ave1XfFHIWGKWVPg4fV7ERV7OgsQ8TJ4VoV4NTOAE8AgkwyAswsgiwsnavVlCIsBbvX8MkFwIWew7GdkVgaVeIjQag2VMQdFeaeQYRHNZCfIsYJlTwUIcPFoZNZAhsB5Z5F5F5dg8A0w6A0Iz5LwSNabMo2lVpN3ONG-AhclAbGwWNccPIlsUYmIL2ewAADy22pDpRTgDgJGDEQEUmYGmM-GUzdAay%20CuHUGpkUgtSAA))

[image]

pattern 2 (pulse from center): [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0mRNIDYDMAmFKnbWAHEmgCwCcJIGIArNZNQKYC0YYAUAB4iMDs5YZXcmkhoQRCuKpSAOgGcAkgGEOXMNyQVudZkW6aUYiSAAKbAO4h0FYpdFo8eKKwuMraG25uRWYJDUYkGmhUGox4dMFBltC%203ChwVEQovGCQKFRMRGwASrbgROJW4VAlRHQ0dJXQVKwAxqrqllSizI0FjlVwXQgxJBhgxJDcidh%20RB2w8M6q9pZ44gEaKPNOLgOO6S2BTaLeLtv2jsyzh071rqJZoVbtJWBMLNGY6ZDhkFJUkESRUJPmXDdxg0NLdvABzYFiIGtEHbSrTTyFURgAqrPIohZIcQYpwAJy4WPyC3WRJKnz2M0cOOOjlOFJpFAcqj6jI6Pm4C2EtJCzNE6DoPTgPRo2XosgAlrIAC4AQwAdrV6NNGFyKDyVa9wI16ar%20Vxdc00QzlsTZpsjQaWmolob6STzTCdk5fKJtnq3StRAATegAMxlAFcADZSxhB%20he8AlTpsfEe8TbUHWbxSp3uQqG04GBB3OAgH3%204NSnyEMSE5iw0K%20Cj5v2BkNhiNRyq-KYu6izCvUJDaaveutFxuRnMxkuiKgsruEYlRAv10Ph4fR1tsdt%20KsaJBMrv9wsNxfN6OwVel7jCVQaYZW2cD-dNkcrscgbgrLt4as72t7hf35eIE%20iPMRzVg4vY3t%20Q6HqOFjTheICwdWFIIZe56IdMZ4CihYFoiE2G4XkFL4VYL5ImiJF5ORXYUqQG5iImbIWDRYiOEBzFoqxQKsVRrD4kQhKJoSOJ0Lo3j4s0jjbOJpLCVoPHUCykkskJYiyfi64gNs6nKSJ0x8TOZYJhohGdtWUlwtME7XvJrpGdM6lTjy5kQta8FMjiW4dGigy2BEZSWFuTgQomQKSQM0YIny55uue1GCaiel0bZFhSTiUkJYRSmopZYhWEhPLuTyZTwjB27Vh54AsnlIJ5vE4hFYFrlUiy5XpuFyUskkfJfDluzoYaXZXhVvUQoN-CiINrXFSA760TNQ0NXNY3TX2Xg4bMCW1QZaIJUxm1MRSoFwYdS3gtNxRLYdk1OJwrghUQ-gDBoJBAuINgAA7BrI9ByGC9ByvQuIylKAD2uJyGgcgABIAF4qK4aQafw%20qYBp7iGDYHxyEocNXOAIgtMkVIiDQr2vZAADWck6NivjAaiAxAnQmBwMqWASY0jCdRp2rsgsXMkBzbPgKk4gRF0VQimKkqygqSouKqAuhKqItTSqZ7c0rmqK86fgAlgeOaiq%20VwLSYjQGQeAkBOWLcPgugoDkAIBdrrjO2FLZ%20RUR41C4Qsu2g6va945xCyw%20uu1SwgtogXRozHkBkInSckLT927H8rMBWH1z69nRqhyLTtUmA%20v0gX3WuLnheiUXeN%20RHwvdQK4us7nXzaKH7cNdT4DEHT2L2NHT496k6sj7TNZzoOB4Pv%20yrK0MVr04vTi5N5pzrzYEDInmaDVBQ%208S9M0W%20UzMUIt1UlC1JFLX2aAVxElFCao-z%20OOV3i%20AYqr1XteZUAMHeZI-wgPhPISw3VX6qlfhLagCIH7602jA1gQA)

[image]

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Fixed your links.

Comment: This is classic "just use a microcontroller" territory ...

Comment: This is just a canned comment to let you know that what you're trying to build from discrete analog components (possibly incorporating Opamps and/or NE555) is a digital control problem and thus can easily and with lower parts count be solved with a microcontroller with really minimal firmware to write.

Comment: how should I implement a microcontroller

Comment: I figured something else out thank you

Comment: Implementing this in a GAL16V8 would be about as nice an exercise as a digit of a decimal U/D counter driving 7 segments.

Comment: Care to explicate *figured something else out*?